# matplotlib's savefig is slow when adding a summary table on a simple pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been using matplotlib to render various charts within automated pdf reports with overall acceptable processing time. However, when I add a summary table below a chart with two axes, there is a significant drop in performance when saving the figure to a file.

So, below is the code to reproduce this chart:
[image: Output]

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import time

data = [
    ['2018-01-01', 50.472, 52.2, 45.1305555555556, 50.399,
     0.983086079622108, 1.00],
    ['2018-02-01', 70.907, 77.5, 69.8916666666667, 79.137,
     1.01918252884086, 0.98],
    ['2018-03-01', 86.148, 124.4, 106.855555555556, 116.661,
     0.920305088314199, 0.89],
    ['2018-04-01', 150.314, 152.5, 143.0, 147.185, 0.877857009149397,
     None],
    ['2018-05-01', 162.63, 191.6, 163.786111111111, 173.851,
     0.834110398117208, 0.86],
    ['2018-06-01', 206.60205, 211.6, 208.858333333333, 214.27,
     0.846595650655765, 0.91],
    ['2018-07-01', 97.374, 219.0, 228.866666666667, 232.978,
     0.794293255390368, 0.71],
    ['2018-08-01', 194.064, 186.5, 187.916666666667, 196.659,
     0.843036593263637, 0.81],
    ['2018-09-01', 154.48, 139.1, 150.969444444444, 157.047,
     0.866042591545732, 0.82],
    ['2018-10-01', 85.029, 89.6, 81.4833333333333, 89.923,
     0.890580752916001, 0.90],
    ['2018-11-01', 46.389, 56.7, 45.0388888888889, 49.594,
     1.3243466016473, 0.98],
    ['2018-12-01', 51.132, 46.3, 47.6777777777778, 50.513,
     0.904260369658414, 1.08]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['day', 'value1',
                                 'value2', 'value3',
                                 'value4',
                                 'value5', 'value6'])


def get_color(column):
    # some logic to retrieve a hex color
    return '#CCCCCC'


matplotlib.use('agg')
init = time.time()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.set_index(df['day'])
grouped_columns = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']
grouped_color_list = [get_color(series) for series in grouped_columns]
df[grouped_columns].plot.bar(rot=0, ax=ax, color=grouped_color_list)
for column in ['value5', 'value6']:
    ax2.plot(df[column], label=column, color=get_color(column))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
values_df = df.T
table = plt.table(cellText=values_df.values,
                  rowLabels=df.columns,
                  colLabels=df.index,
                  cellLoc='center', rowLoc='center',
                  loc='bottom')
plotting_time = time.time() - init
print('Chart plot took {:.2f}s'.format(plotting_time))
fig.savefig('output.png', bbox_inches='tight', format='png', dpi=100)
saving_time = time.time() - init
print('savefig took {:.2f}s'.format(saving_time))
```

Here is the console output (with table):

```
Chart plot took 0.17s
savefig took 4.48s
```

Here is the console output (without table):

```
Chart plot took 0.13s
savefig took 0.62s
```

Is there somewhere I'm not using the plot features correctly?

Comment: The timings are a bit misleading. Drawing the canvas is what takes most of the time when creating matplotlib plots. Timing the drawing (`fig.canvas.draw()`) will result in a similar time than saving. A valid question would hence be why it takes more than a second to draw the table.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out what's going on with the table that takes so long ?

Comment: I suspect that it's the autoadjustment of the fontsize to match the maximum cell size that would still fit inside the table. If you add `table.auto_set_font_size(False)` it will be a lot faster, but you would need to set the font size manually.

Comment: That is one the point ! Falling back to 1.2 s after setting `table.auto_set_font_size(False)`. Now onto figuring out a way to "simply" set the font size.

Comment: It may or may not help answer this question: I just learned `bbox_inches='tight'` results in draw() to be called twice. In my case it was adding 30% to execution time of `savefig()`